# Maven and Gradle nested dependencies

Tags: maven, gradle, repository

I have a library A that uses a library B. These two libraries are then used by application C.

Both library A and B can be found in a maven repository.

I have tried to add B as a dependency to A by adding it into A's POM file.

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach or there is a standard way to do this.

I am looking for either the standard way of doing this or a reference guide to point me into the right direction.

Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide.

Comment: Yes, it's the correct approach. It's the whole point of dependencies.

Comment: I think the definition you are looking for is _transitive dependencies_, which Maven and Gradle both handle. For example see the [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) and [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) for some documentation on it.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, so application C will only need to include A which will then cause A and B to be brought in?

Comment: Thanks! transitive dependencies seems to be the term I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term for such relationship is called a *transitive dependency*. In your application, you define just the *direct* dependencies, the *transitive* ones are handled by a particular build system (*Gradle*, *Maven*, *Ant + Ivy*).

For example, considering following *Gradle* build script:

```java
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.2'
}
```

You can list this project dependencies with the command:

```
$ gradle dependencies
```

This should provide result similar to (depends on the *Gradle* version, this one is 4.4.1):

```
testCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
\--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.2
     +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.0.0
     \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.0.2
```

Therefore, `opentest4j` and `junit-platform-commons` are *transitive* dependencies of the `junit-jupiter-api` library, which is the only *direct* dependency of the project.

It's equivalent for *Maven*. E.g. you can list Maven dependencies with:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
```